# Processing a pyqtSignal using event loop exec()

Tags: pyqt

In code below a `signal` is processed (triggering `slot`) without calling `app.exec()`.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot


class Worker(QObject):
    signal = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        self.signal.emit(1)


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        worker = Worker()
        worker.signal.connect(self.slot)
        worker.run()

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def slot(self, num):
        print(num)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MyWindow()
window.show()
# app.exec()
```

As I know, in PyQt a signal is sent to an event queue when `emit()` is called, and processed when `exec()` of an event loop is called.

But the `signal` above seems to be processed without any event loop.

So I want the `signal` above to be processed only after app.exec() is called. Is it possible?

Comment: Is that worker supposed to be a separate thread?

Comment: @musicamante No. It's just an example code... Actually I'm processing events (defined in an external package) through main event loop and want to put a custom event (signal) into the main event queue so that it is processed synchronously with other events.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're trying to do, in any case, right now I see two main issues: the `worker` instance will get garbage collected as soon as `__init__` returns (so you should make it an instance member, like `self.worker`), then you could try to call the `run` using a singleshot QTimer (`QTimer.singleShot(0, self.worker.run)`), but if you're dealing with external events you *must* be absolutely sure that their processing is not blocking, otherwise you'll need a QThread in any case.

Comment: @DavidJohns Signals are always processed synchronously by default, unless Qt detects that the sender and receiver are in different threads. A running event-loop is only required for asynchronous signals. So your example works exactly as expected.